# Rails 4 avoiding repeated POST request, slow redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My CompaniesController works great but I noticed an annoying flaw. When a user accindently doubleclicks the submit button to create his company the controller would add the company multiple times. When I then added validation to check for the uniqueness of the name it only creates one such company, but if the user doubleclicks he gets the errormessage that the company already exists before the controller can redirect to the company show page :/ Anyone have any idea how to fix this bug?

Comment: So what actually do you want to have?
Redirect after validation message? - or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable the submit button using JavaScript upon form submission:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    $(this).find('input:submit').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzbvzu86/1/)